# Update with joining another table

Tags: mysql, join, update

I would like to update `cities_extended.city_id` based on a join with `cities`

Table `cities`

```
CREATE TABLE `cities` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `state_code` char(2) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `state_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `cities`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

Table `cities_extended`

```
CREATE TABLE `cities_extended` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `state_code` char(2) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `zip` int(5) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
  `latitude` double NOT NULL,
  `longitude` double NOT NULL,
  `county` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `state_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `city_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `cities_extended`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `cities_extended`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;COMMIT;
```

Update command

```
UPDATE cities_extended
SET cities_extended.`city_id` = cities.`id`
FROM cities_extended  
INNER JOIN  cities
ON
    cities_extended.`state_id` = cities.`state_id`
AND
    cities_extended.`city`= cities.`city`
```

Results in

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
        that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the 
        right syntax to use near 
            'FROM   
               cities_extended
            JOIN
                cities
            ON
                cities_extended.`state_id' at line 5
```

Giving this error can you help me

Answer (score 5):

MySQL's syntax for `UPDATE` does not have `FROM` (you probably got the syntax from a SQL Server example).

The [syntax in MySQL is](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html):

```
UPDATE 
     <table_references>   -- this can be multiple tables joined 
                         -- with the JOIN .. ON syntax
SET 
     column_name_1 = value1,
     column_name_2 = value2
WHERE 
     <conditions>
... ;
```

Try this:

```
UPDATE
        cities_extended
    INNER JOIN
        cities
    ON
        cities_extended.state_id = cities.state_id
    AND
        cities_extended.city = cities.city
SET
    cities_extended.city_id = cities.id ;
```

or with table aliases:

```
UPDATE
        cities_extended AS ce
    INNER JOIN
        cities AS c
    ON
        ce.state_id = c.state_id
    AND
        ce.city = c.city
SET
    ce.city_id = c.id ;
```